# Set background color of a control? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

How can I set the backcolor of a control (equivilant of control.backcolor in .Net). I tried setBKColor with no luck.

ex: TabHwnd = createWindowEx(NULL,WC_TAB....

then how could I set the back color of TabHwnd?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will generate a message when it's painting the background of a control, and it is up to your program to respond to the message appropriately.

- [WM_CTLCOLORBTN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761849(VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_CTLCOLOREDIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761691(VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_CTLCOLORDLG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645417(VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761360(VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_CTLCOLORSCROLLBAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787573(VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787524(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but perhaps this answer will still help some others.

What worked for me was to return a hollow brush for the background color messages.  For example:

```
switch (msg) {
  case WM_CTLCOLORDLG:
    return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
  case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    return (INT_PTR)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
}
```

Also, you don't need to worry about deleting the "brushes" created by GetStockObject.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing (see SetClassLong) and process WM_ERASEBKGND

Comment: There's no WinAPI function to do such a thing?